# NSolve/FindRoot matrix equation and conditions

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, numerics, linear-algebra

I have an eigenvalue (vector) problem (please see the theory, maybe I missed something in the post or did not understand Eqs (3.5.24) [image: pp1] [image: pp2]  [image: pp3] [image: pp4] [image: pp5]) how to obtain two unknown matrices (36 unknowns) to satisfy all given conditions. Unknown matrices are

```
 XX = Table[X[10 i + j], {i, 6}, {j, 3}];
 YY = Table[Y[10 i + j], {i, 6}, {j, 3}];
```

which should be joined and present the 36 unknowns

```
 unknown = ArrayFlatten[({{XX, YY}})];
```

Let's suppose that we have two matrices in the following form:

```
JJ = {{0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 1.`, 0.`, 0.`}, {0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 1.`, 
0.`}, {0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 1.`}, {-1.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 
0.`}, {0.`, -1.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`}, {0.`, 0.`, -1.`, 0.`, 0.`, 
0.`}};

 HH={{5.33449*10^7, -3.14159*10^7, 3.99684*10^6, 0., 199.842, 
 0.}, {-3.14159*10^7, 2.82358*10^7, -200000., -200., 
 0., -199.842}, {3.99684*10^6, -200000., 4.23581*10^6, 0., 199.842, 
 0.}, {0., -200., 0., 0.01, 0., 0.}, {199.842, 0., 199.842, 0., 
 0.00999211, 0.}, {0., -199.842, 0., 0., 0., 0.00999211}};
```

We obtained eigenvalues s1, s2 and s3, (s4=-s1, s5=-s2, s6=-s3) and take theirs imaginary parts

```
q0 = Eigenvalues[N[{HH, JJ}, 5]];

s1 = N[Im[q0]][[5]];
s2 = N[Im[q0]][[3]];
s3 = N[Im[q0]][[1]];
```

to construct the diagonal matrix s in the form

```
s = {{s1, 0, 0}, {0, s2, 0}, {0, 0, s3}};
```

Now, we need to satisfy (find unknowns) with NSolve or FindRoot all conditions where

```
 zero = Table[0, {i, 3}, {j, 3}];
 onem = IdentityMatrix[3];


 one = Transpose[XX].JJ.XX;
 two = Transpose[YY].JJ.YY;
 three = Transpose[YY].HH.XX;
 four = Transpose[XX].HH.YY;

 five = Transpose[XX].HH.XX;
 six = Transpose[YY].HH.YY;
 seven = Transpose[XX].JJ.YY;
 eight = -Transpose[YY].JJ.XX;


 FindRoot[{one == zero, two == zero, three == zero, four == zero, 
 five == s, six == s, seven == onem, 
eight == onem}, {{X[11], 1}, {X[12], 1}, {X[13], 1}, {X[21], 
1}, {X[22], 1}, {X[23], 1}, {X[31], 1}, {X[32], 1}, {X[33], 
1}, {X[41], 1}, {X[42], 1}, {X[43], 1}, {X[51], 1}, {X[52], 
1}, {X[53], 1}, {X[61], 1}, {X[62], 1}, {X[63], 1}, {Y[11], 
1}, {Y[12], 1}, {Y[13], 1}, {Y[21], 1}, {Y[22], 1}, {Y[23], 
1}, {Y[31], 1}, {Y[32], 1}, {Y[33], 1}, {Y[41], 1}, {Y[42], 
1}, {Y[43], 1}, {Y[51], 1}, {Y[52], 1}, {Y[53], 1}, {Y[61], 
1}, {Y[62], 1}, {Y[63], 1}}]
```

but we have more equations then unknowns. If I fill use only first four equations, I can get the solution, but how to satisfy the rest number of equations?

Also, I choose roots around 1. How to get one set of solutions to satisfy all 8 matrix equations?

Comment: `FindInstance` might be helpful. Anyways, if you end up with more equations than unknowns, then you might have redundancies in your equations or your problem is not well-posed in the first place. Are you sure that your problem should have solutions? Can you tell in advance how many solutions there might be?

Comment: there are a more solutions... it is posted well for sure, these conditions are simple eigen vector problem and they are well known as a conditions of symplectic matrix... if you know a way to find only one solution, please write

Comment: If it is really only an eigenvector problem, then it should be solvable with `Eigensystem`. You need to `Flatten` your matrix variables and rephrase left and right multiplication by other matices as linear mapping on the flattened matrix variables.

Comment: thanks for the comment, can you please check what you wrote because i am not sure that you explained well

Comment: Before I start with that, would you please be so kind and write down the mathematica eigenvalue problem at the beginning your question (in $\LaTeX$ if possible)? I am not sure if I understood you correctly. I might write an extended answer afterwards.

Comment: I can only provide the scan of the document from the book. But please give me the suggestion how?

Comment: When you edit your post there is a toolbar on top of the editor. The sixth symbol from the left allows you to upload images.

Comment: done. The summarized conditions are in Eq. 3.5.24 in the theory

Comment: As I read that, I understand the section "Orthogonal properties..." as a bonus and not as the defining relations for the matrices $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{Y}$. You can get `XX` and `YY` simply as the matrices whose colums are the eigenvectors of the eigenvalue problems 3.5.14.a and 3.5.14.b. And that can be done _directly_ with `Eigensystem` (you might have to transpose the matrix of eigenvectors produced by `Eigensystem` since it contains the eigenvectors as rows, not as columns).

Comment: Henrik can you please post this what you said because I am not sure that I can simple handle like you are writing and it will be the solution of the problem... thank you a lot in advance

Comment: and also is that mean that if we have the Eigenvalues consisted only with imaginary parts, matrix XX will be zero and YY should satisfy 3.5.14b?

Comment: So I need this Transpose[Eigensystem[HH.JJ.HH]]? Bit I got some strange form of that. The output is not the matrix

Comment: Try `{lambda, XX}={#1,Transpose[#2]}&@@Eigensystem[HH.JJ.HH]`. I am occupied at the moment. Will answer tonight.

Comment: ok Henrik, please respond me tonight and thank you very very much

Comment: I also tried {vals, vecs} = Eigensystem[[HH.JJ.HH]]; but vals are not the Eigenvalues which should be the same with Eigenvalues[N[{HH, JJ}, 20]] and then what is a XX in that case?

Comment: I still can not satisfy with T=(XX YY) the conditions given by Eqs. (3.5.25) and (3.5.26)

Comment: I also tried this {vals, vecs} = Eigensystem[N[{HH.JJ.HH, JJ}, 50] and got the 6x6 matrix, but is this symplectic matrix? I did not satisfy conditions 3.5.25. and 3.5.26

Answer (score 1):

The book's author's primary goal seems to be his self-entertainment.

He wants to solve the first order ODE

$$\dot{\mathbf{u}}(t) = \mathbf{J} \, \mathbf{H} \, \mathbf{u}(t)$$

and applies an exponential ansatz

$$ \mathbf{u} = \sum_{r=1}^{2 n} \hat{\mathbf{u}}_r  \operatorname{e}^{\lambda_r \,t + c_r}$$

with integration constants $c_r$ and solutions $(\hat{\mathbf{u}}_r,\lambda_r)$ of the eigenvalue problem

$$\mathbf{J} \, \mathbf{H} \, \mathbf{u}_r = \lambda_r \, \mathbf{u}_r.$$

So. Let's. Just. Solve. That.

```
n = 3;
JJ = ArrayFlatten[{{ConstantArray[0., {n, n}], 
     N@IdentityMatrix[n]}, {-N@IdentityMatrix[n], 
     ConstantArray[0., {n, n}]}}];
HH = N[{{4.9348022005446793094172455`5.*^7, -3.1415926535897937`*^7, 
     0, 0, 0, 0}, {-3.1415926535897937`*^7, 
     2.0238963636413604`*^7, -200000.`5., 0, 0, 0}, {0, -200000.`5., 
     238963.6364136009748945761`5., 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0.01`5., 0, 
     0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0099921105457425255`5., 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
     0.0099921105457425255`5.}}];

{λ, vecs} = Eigensystem[JJ.HH];
```

*Bamm.* That's it.

Let's synthesize the general solution $\mathbf{u}(t)$ of the ODE and test it:

```
u = t \[Function] Evaluate[Simplify[Total[Exp[t λ + Array[C, Length[λ]]] vecs]]];
u'[t] - JJ.HH.u[t] // Simplify // Chop
```

> {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}

Done.

Afterwards, the author means to say (but he did't):

$$\mathbf{x}_r = \Re(\hat{\mathbf{u}}_e) \quad \text{and} \quad \mathbf{y}_r = \Im(\hat{\mathbf{u}}_r).$$

In Mathematica terms, this is

```
x = Re[vecs];
y = Im[vecs];
```

Afterwards, he collects a bunch of equations that are automatically satisfied. Here are some of them (3.5.12 and 3.5.13):

```
ppos = Flatten[Position[λ/I // Chop, _?Positive]];
npos = Flatten[Position[λ/I // Chop, _?Negative]];
ω = 0.5 (λ[[ppos]]/I - λ[[npos]]/I) // Chop;

Table[HH.x[[ppos[[i]]]] - (ω[[i]] JJ.y[[ppos[[i]]]]), {i, 1, n}] // Chop
Table[HH.x[[npos[[i]]]] - (-ω[[i]] JJ.y[[npos[[i]]]]), {i, 1, n}] // Chop
```

> {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}
>
> {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}

The matrices $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{Y}$ can be obtained from that by

```
XX = Transpose[x[[1 ;; n]]];
YY = Transpose[y[[1 ;; n]]];
```

I leave checking all the other conditions to you.

Comment: Dear Henrik, thank you for your post, but the XX and YY matrices should be 3x6 that T=(XX YY) be 2nx2n (6x6) so that the conditions 3.5.25 and 3.5.26 should be satisfied, but there are not.

Comment: try with this matrix HH which I provided, because this HH matrix satisfy condition to have real and imaginary part of eigenvector. With code up something must be different that we can satisfy conditions 3.5.25 and 3.5.26

Comment: for sure XX and YY are not good

Comment: Henrik can you please just extract XX and YY which I need?

Comment: Henrik can you please take a look on Eq. 3.5.12. It is written that H (6x6) matrix multiple vector xr(3x1). This is strange I can not form the T matrix. I determined the eigenvector what you wrote, it is simple. Matrix T is a point of the question

Comment: you wrote on complex way simple thing what can be obtained using only Eigenvector function. I do not understand why you wrote this?

Comment: I solved, not what you wrote. This I need, not to check combinations, no combinations   {vals, vecs} = Eigensystem[{HH // N, -JJ // N}] // Chop;

n2 = Length[vecs];
XX = Re[vecs[[1 ;; n2 ;; 2]]];
YY = Im[vecs[[1 ;; n2 ;; 2]]];

n = n2/2;

DD = XX.JJ.Transpose[YY];

XX = Table[XX[[i]]/Sqrt[DD[[i, i]]], {i, 1, n}];
YY = Table[YY[[i]]/Sqrt[DD[[i, i]]], {i, 1, n}];

TT = Join[XX, YY] // Transpose;